# Implementing Blind Spot Convolution in Tensorflow v2

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm unable to understand how to implement [blind spot convolution](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.11010.pdf).

The idea is to have the center value in the kernel as 0 (untrainable) and do regular convolutions, but I'm unable to find how to achieve this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[Answer in Comments, to be closed]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can be solved by multiplying a mask with 0 at center and 1 everywhere else. Multiply this mask to the filter and ensure that the mask is untrainable.

Comment: @cmaspi you should post a self-answer to your question. It might be useful to other people.